# Does Ramban's 8th principle require holding the Masoretic Text to be perfectly preserved?

Tags: tanach, rambam, mesorah-tradition

If Rambam's 8th principle is accepted, is it neccessary to hold that the Masoretic Text is perfectly preserved, and superior to the Dead Sea Scrolls and Septuagint in all cases where there are disagreements?

Comment: Yes, but it is not certain that Rambam himself held this way.

Comment: Ive wondered this too. I don't think its perfectly clear according to his text. Good question!